# Why aren't inserted user values matching file values?

Tags: c, file

lately i've been working on a project that gives me a file containing an integer with 16 numbers followed by an integer with 4 numbers (card number and password). My goal is to create a user-password system that, after 3 unsuccessful login attempts, shuts down. Now, this isn't an issue, my problem is that not matter how i make the code, my input (be it card number or password) won't match the file values. Here's my code

```
typedef struct{
   int number[16];
   int pass[4];
} TypeCard;

int main(void)
{
   int i, c = 0, n, p, cards;

   TypeCard card;

   FILE *f = fopen("cards.txt", "r");

   for(i = 0; fscanf(f, "%d %d", card.number, card.pass)!= EOF; i++)
   {
      cards++; /*this is merely to fill this loop, i don't know if ill need it*/
   }

   fclose(f);

   while(c != 3)  /*c is a counter */
   {
      int al = 2 - c;  /*al = attempts left*/

      printf("Insert card number: ");
      scanf("%d", &n);

      if(n == card.number[i])
      { 
          printf("Insert password: ");
          scanf("%d", &p);

          if(p == card.pass[i])
          {
              printf("Access granted\n");
              return 0;
          }
          else
          {
              printf("Wrong password\n");
              printf("Attempts left: %d\n", al);
              c++;
          }
      }
      else
      {
          printf("Invalid card\n");
          printf("Attempts left: %d\n", al);
          printf("Try again.\n\n");
          c++;
      } 
  }

  printf("Access blocked. Please contact the system administrator.\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Each iteration of the loop - what do you think this is doing `fscanf(f, "%d %d", card.number, card.pass)` - I guess this is not your intention

Comment: @EdHeal Isn't that supposed to be storing the int values from the file into the members of the struct?

Comment: Try the first members of the array! I guess you want to fill up the arrays. You need to check the bound as well. Also you can have an empty loop so `cards++;` is not required

Comment: @EdHeal I have, nothing works, neither the first members nor the last ones. I just tried making the struct elements integers and adjust the code properly but even that doesn't help. And as for the loop part, thank you i tought that if the loop was empty the function wouldnt work

Comment: 1. Check if you have opened the file (i.e. `f` is not full). 2. Learn to use a debugger

Comment: 3. What is the contents of `card.txt`

Comment: I mentioned it in the description, if it wasn't clear it contains several times 16 digits number (space) 4 digits number, for example "4024007147275431 9532". And as for your comment of the debugger, i need to install one, im using geanie in ubuntu, which doesn't come with debugger

Comment: 1. Install a debugger 2. Read the number as a array of characters.

Comment: And what is the contents of `card.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to read a 16 digit number into an int which has at most 32 bits which can only handle 10 digits. To handle 16 digits you need to use 'long long' which is 64 bits and can handle 20 digits.